# Can I automatically populate multiple ImageViews with SVG assets?

Tags: android

I am building an app that needs to display one SVG image at a time inside an ImageView. I wish to have a selection of a hundred different images, and iterate in whatever data structure (I think map is the best?) one image at a time.

Ideally i'd like to upload all my images to my project and loop through all of them until each one is assigned to an imageview, each with a key of its filename. Something like:

```
       Map<String, ImageView> imageViewMap; 
       for (int i = 0; i <svgFolderSize;i++) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nextSVGFileInFolder);
            imageViewMap.put(nextSVGFileInFolder.fileName().toString(),img); 
        }
```

Is this possible or if I say have a 100 SVG's, I need to manually assign each one to its corresponding ImageView and then give a unique key?

Comment: yes that's possible. But consider using a list instead of 100 separate imageviews

Comment: @TimCastelijns Ok i understand the list part. But what about getting svg folder length and getting the nextFile() etc? How do you do that?:

Comment: i'm with what @TimCastelijns said. Also maybe take a look at the RecyclerView which is built exactly for cases like this.

Comment: Recently someone had a similar question to which I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657713/5015207) - maybe it will help with accessing the drawables